# Python/Django to PHP transition ? Wrong learning Curve?

Tags: php, python, django, programming-languages

I have been coding in python/django and c/c++ from last three years for various web-based and desktop applications in my previous companies. While following the general learning curve, I started working on functional programming languges like Haskell/Erlang. But recently I switched to a company where the programming languages used are php and Java.

Having switched to python did change the way I used to code, mostly in good sense, and then learning haskell added another dimension to the thought process.

I would like to know if:

- Learning php and java (I have done a     project in groovy/grails too) would      be like stepping back on the learning    curve?
- The present company          basically uses smarty as a template      engine, also    there is no ORM which    is kind of    frustrating after          having worked in    django, Is there     any way ORM and    other such          features can be included?
- Does      it make sense to continue learning       python/haskell assuming that    I        will be staying in the present           company for pretty long ?
- Also, what can be the right way to move from python to php? I know its wierd because usually people ask the other way around (php to python)

Comment: The right way to move from Python to PHP is at 120mph straight down.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but porting down the whole code from php to python will take a long time, and is not commercially viable for the company, so anyhow I am supposed to learn it, though I am hating the experience.

Comment: Unfortunately all I can suggest is that you hunt down the largest bottle of naproxen that you can find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you must do step down to php, at least use one of the good available MVC frameworks with an ORM:

  - [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)
  - [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)
  - More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648/what-php-framework-would-you-choose-for-a-new-application-and-why
- Adopt the good parts of using the framework:  Don't forget to write tests as you move to php!
- Keep database/serialized objects simple and clear - so they can be accessed from other programming languages in parallel or when you move out of php world.  I.e., don't use php's `serialize()`, but json, protobufs, thrift.
- Try to keep the php portions of your code as small as possible and limited to web frontend - fight any attempt to create new backend services using php, which is not so good in memory management, threading etc.  If you already use Java, you can use it for this purpose (or intrduce python...)
- http://www.phpsh.org/ is your new ipython, although not as useful
- If possible, try sticking to php 5.3 with namespaces and better memory management

Comment: Thanks Udi. Zend is being used already, although I still see people making raw db queries in the code which doesnt make much sense. Also, not having namespaces is considered a good point for php, isnt it?

Comment: @bilkubekar: namespaces are many times a matter of personal taste.  Usually python programmers love them and php programmers don't:  It is  hard to tame existing code to use namespaces, and does not make sense in many php contexts.  However php 5.3 have other goodies as anonymous functions.